# why page refreshed when i click on submit button..and textbox value becomes empty

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   

    // Fetching all HTML inputs

    var fullname=document.forms["myform"]["fullname"];
    var email=document.forms["myform"]["email"];
    var mobile=document.forms["myform"]["mobile"];
    var password=document.forms["myform"]["password"];
    var confirmpassword=document.forms["myform"]["confirmpassword"];

    //Fetching html component by their ID

    var fullname_error=document.getElementById("fullname_error");
    var email_error=document.getElementById("email_error");
    var mobile_error=document.getElementById("mobile_error");
    var password_error=document.getElementById("password_error");
    var confirmpassword_error=document.getElementById("confirmpassword_error");

    // Setting  event listner for  all inputs


    fullname.addEventListener("blur", nameVerify, true);
    email.addEventListener("blur()", emailVerify, true);
    mobile.addEventListener("blur()", mobileVerify, true);
    password.addEventListener("blur()", passwordVerify, true);
    confirmpassword.addEventListener("blur()", confirmpasswordVerify, true);





    function validate()
    {

     if (fullname.value=="") 
     {
      fullname.style.borderColor = 'red';
      fullname_error.textContent="Fullname is required";
      fullname.focus();
      return false;
     }
     else
     {

     }
    }   

    function nameVerify()
    {
     if (fullname.value !="") {

      fullname_error.innerHTML="";
      return true;
     }
     else {
      
     }
    } 
  
</script>
```

```css
.cssfullname
{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Registration</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
 

</head>
<body>
 
 

  <form role="form" method="post"  name="myform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <div>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;" name="fullname" placeholder="Fullname">
    <br>
    <div id="fullname_error" class="cssfullname"></div>
   </div>

   <div>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" class="form-control " style="width: 200px; name="email" placeholder="Email" >
    <br>
    <div id="email_error"></div>
   </div>

   <div>
    <input type="text" id="txt3" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile">
    <br>
    <div id="mobile_error"></div>
   </div>

   <div>
    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control"  style="width: 200px;name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <div id="password_error"></div>
   </div>

   <div>
    <input type="password" id="passcon" class="form-control" style="width: 200px; name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <br><br>
    <div id="confirmpassword_error"></div>
   </div>

   <div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="validate()" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit">
    <br>
   </div>
  
  
  </form>
 

 
</body>
</html>
How to overcome that problem? what to do
when i click on submit....text becomes empty.........................................................
```

the error message also removed when click on submit button.the error message also removed when click on submit button.the error message also removed when click on submit button.the error message also removed when click on submit button.the error message also removed when click on submit button.the error message also removed when click on submit button.the error message also removed when click on submit button.

Comment: You're submitting the form, and your server sends a new page as a response to the submission.

Comment: Then what to do ?

Comment: Quick and dirty, remove the onclick from the submit button, and put the inline handler to the form this way: `onsubmit="return validate()"`, and take care that `validate` returns `false` when you don't want to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks bro got it? now it is working